# Resolving type ambiguities using available class instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ambiguity, ambiguous

Given the following code:

```
import Data.Word

data T = T deriving (Eq, Show)

class    C a      where f :: a -> ()
instance C T      where f _ = ()
instance C Word16 where f _ = ()

main = return $ f 0x16
```

GHC complains that it can't infer what the type for the literal `0x16` should be with the error:

```
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal ‘22’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

It is easy to see why this would be -- Haskell allows numeric literals to be of any type which has an instance of `Num`, and here we can't disambiguate what the type for the literal `0x16` (or 22) should be.

It's also clear as a human reading this what I intended to do -- there is only one available instance of the class `C` which satisfies the `Num` constraint, so obviously I intended to use that one so `0x16` should be treated as a `Word16`.

There are two ways that I know to fix it: Either annotate the literal with its type:

```
main = return $ f (0x16 :: Word16)
```

or define a function which essentially does that annotation for you:

```
w16 x = x :: Word16
main = return $ f (w16 0x16)
```

I have tried a third way, sticking `default (Word16)` at the top of the file in the hope that Haskell would pick that as the default type for numeric literals, but I guess I'm misunderstanding what the `default` keyword is supposed to do because that didn't work.

I understand that typeclasses are open, so just because you can make the assumption in the context quoted above that `Word16` is the only numeric instance of `C` that may not hold in some other module.  But my question is: is there some mechanism by which I can assume/enforce that property, so that it is possible to use `f` and have Haskell resolve the type of its numeric argument to `Word16` without explicit annotations at the call site?

The context is that I am implementing an EDSL, and I would rather not have to include manual type hints when I know that my parameters will either be `Word16` or some other non-numeric type.  I am open to a bit of dirty types/extensions abuse if it makes the EDSL feel more natural!  Although if solutions do involve the naughty pragmas I'd definitely appreciate hints on what I should be wary about when using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution with "naughty pragmas" with GHC 7.10:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class    C a where f :: a -> ()
instance C T where f _ = ()
instance {-# INCOHERENT #-} (w ~ Word16) => C w where f _ = ()
```

And with GHC 7.8:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}

class    C a where f :: a -> ()
instance C T where f _ = ()
instance (w ~ Word16) => C w where f _ = ()
```

Here, GHC essentially picks an arbitrary most specific instance that remains after trying to unify the instances heads and constraints.

You should only use this if

- You have a fixed set of instances and don't export the class.
- For all use cases of the class method, there is a single possible most specific instance (given the constraints).

Many people advise against *ever* using `IncoherentInstances`, but I think it can be quite fun for DSL-s, if we observe the above considerations.

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you!  Yeah, I'm basically abusing typeclasses to give me a sort of overloading on certain instructions in my EDSL -- in the end only those instructions and not the typeclass they rely on will be exported, so I think I should be safe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For anybody else wondering about `default` (I know I was!)

https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3

Quoting section 4.3.4:

> In situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type variable, v, is defaultable if:
>
> - v appears only in constraints of the form C v, where C is a class, and
> - at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, Num or a subclass of Num), and
> - all of these classes are defined in the Prelude or a standard library.

So that explains why your `default` clause is being completely ignored; `C` is not a standard library type-class.

(As to *why* this is the rule… can't help you there. Presumably to avoid breaking arbitrary user-defined code.)

Comment: This last restriction is lifted by the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension.